# Pressure Sensor BMP183 and Raspberry Pi 2B

Tags: sensor, driver

I have a BMP183 (from Adafruit) and I'm trying to make it work on my Raspberry Pi 2B, but I'm getting the following error:

```
BMP183 returned ',#randomnumber#, ' instead of 0x55. Communication failed, expect problems
```

I've tried this code [BMP183](https://github.com/PrzemoF/bmp183) both master and threaded.
I tried to modify the PIN in the code in the `def __init__(self)` function and I still get the same error.

[Board and connection:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wlt0.jpg)

- CS on CE0 (pin 24), red cable;
- SDI on MOSI (pin 19), orange cable;
- SDO on MISO (pin 21), yellow cable;
- SCK in SCLK (pin 23), green
  cable;

Is there anything that I did wrong?

Comment: Looks okay.  Does the DHT11 work okay?

Comment: Yes, DHT11 and a SRD-05vdc-sl-c dual channel relay works fine too.
I haven't solder the BMP183 with the pins as in this link https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bmp183-spi-barometric-pressure-and-altitude-sensor/assembly ... should it be a contact problem?

Answer (score 1):

The code on GitHub you reference doesn't use the SPI interface.
You could try using the same pins as shown there.

```
CS -> 16
SDI -> 12
SDO -> 10
SCK -> 8
```

Alternatively, you could use the Adafruit BMP Python library which **does** support SPI.